# Spring : Difference between @ControllerAdvice and Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring-mvc

The `@ControllerAdvice` annotation allows us to write global code applicable to a wide range of controllers.

My Question is:

`@ControllerAdvice` is applicable to only controller level and Spring AOP is based on pointcut.

Other than this, what are the differences between them and when to use `@ControllerAdvice`and Spring AOP?

I was trying to implement something like shown in this example link.

[Link Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-controlleradvice-annotation-example/)

Answer (score 8):

`@ControllerAdvice` is one of the AOP features Spring offers. The main difference in use case is that `@ControllerAdvice` is wired up by the Spring MVC infrastructure and uses (and provides) Web-specific features. Use it if you're writing advice that specifically applies to Web requests, such as error handling (e.g., translating exceptions into an enterprise-standard JSON error format). Otherwise, aspects are the approach.